# how to find the exact location where java is installed in unix

Tags: java, unix

I am using SSH Client. I have run the environment variable still

echo $JAVA_HOME is not returning anything. I want to find the exact location where the java is installed in unix. is there any other command which can help me with this ?

Answer (score 8):

The `which` command gives you the path to the `java` binary:

```
which java
```

But if it is only a symlink (e.g. used by `alternatives`) this will not get your the real path to the binary. You can either list where the symlink points to with with `ls -l`:

```
ls -l `which java`
```

which for me outputs

```
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

and then follow the symlinks until you are at the source. Alternatively, if available on your system, use the `readlink` command in combination with `-f` which follows symlinks for you:

```
readlink -f `which java`
```

Edit: Ankit wrote in the comments that `readlink` is not a standard UNIX command and `-f` also does not seem to work on a mac, so this may not be an option for you, although [this](http://biercoff.com/fixing-readlink-illegal-option-f-error-on-a-mac/) page describes how to get `greadlink` to get this functionality on a mac via `brew`:

> brew install coreutils
>   greadlink -f `which java`

Comment: readlink is not standard to unix. besides it will fail in case of symlink path is also a symlink

Comment: That is what the `-f` is for. It follows symlinks until it not a symlink anymore.

Comment: on mac, -f is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

since `echo $JAVA_HOME` is not giving you the path, this variable is probably not already set. Instead, [which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(Unix)) command would give you the path.

```
which java
```

Note that, this might not give you the exact location if command is a `symlink`. If that is the case, you must resolve the `symlink` through other methods.
say `readlink` or through python `(os.path.realpath(path))`

Comment: NB: the path might be a symlink

Comment: I posted an answer that does include symlink handling.

Answer (score 3):

Can you run ?

`whereis java`

As far as I remmember it gives symbolic link to location.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix you should be able to use the 'which java' command.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(Unix)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with these 2 commands

`$ which java`

`$ whereis java`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`$ which java`

might result output as

`/usr/bin/java`

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily find the Java Home Directory by appending  `/jre`  to the output directory of the below command

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

Sample output will be

```
java-11-oracle                 1091       /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle
```

Now append `/jre` which makes the JAVA HOME as

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/jre
```